# C++ segfault with lists

Tags: c++

My code segfaults on the last line here:

```
Level level1;
level1.generateLevel();
list<Entity>* obstacles;
//Get level obstacles
obstacles = level1.obstacleList;
```

Obviously there's something wrong with the way I handle the list, but I'm not sure what exactly. This is the code that handles the list.

```
for (int row = 0; row<6; row++)
{
    level_position_x = -128;
    for (int column = 0; column<8; column++)
    {
        level_position_x = level_position_x + tile_offset;
        if (room_array[row][column] == 1)
        {
            obstacleList->push_front(*new Obstacle("images/ground.png", level_position_x, 768 - level_position_y - tile_offset));
        }
    }
}
```

I know that when dealing with arrays like I have in my for loop that they're often the source of crashes, but I'm fairly certain that with the rest of my code that room_array isn't the culprit. Is there something immediate that I'm missing that's causing this?

Comment: Don't use `*new`. That's an instant memory leak.

Comment: We need more informations, like the declaration `obstacleList` for example

Comment: please provide a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).